# How to access random indices from h5 data set?

Tags: python, h5py

I have some h5 data that I want to sample from by using some randomly generated indices. However, if the indices are out of increasing order, then the effort fails. Is it possible to select indices, that have been generated randomly, from h5 data sets?

Here is a MWE citing the error:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.random(50).reshape(10,5)
with h5py.File('example1.h5', 'w') as h5fw:
    h5fw.create_dataset('data', data=arr)

random_subset = h5py.File('example1.h5', 'r')['data'][[3, 1]]

# TypeError: Indexing elements must be in increasing order
```

I *could* sort the indices, but then we lose the randomness component.

Comment: WIth `numpy` arrays in memory, random indices aren't a problem.  But in an `h5` file, it's much more efficient to access elements in sorted order.  File reads back and forth are slow.  So you need to sort the indices, and figure out some way of randomizing the loaded array afterwards..

Comment: Hmm thank you. I am finding that even my accessing of select indices, in sorted order, is quite the slow process. The post randomization does pose another problem.

Comment: Yes, the docs do warn that indexing like this slow.  Fetching slices is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hpaulj mentioned, random indices aren't a problem for numpy arrays in memory. So, yes it's possible to select data with randomly generated indices ***from h5 data sets read to numpy arrays***. The key is having sufficient memory to hold the dataset in memory. The code below shows how to do this:

```
#random_subset = h5py.File('example1.h5', 'r')['data'][[3, 1]]
arr = h5py.File('example1.h5', 'r')['data'][:]
random_subset = arr[[3,1]]
```

Comment: I am now seeing that by accessing `n` indices of my h5 file that I am running into memory issues. Can you comment on how I might access random slices of my H5 data set **without** h5 wanting to place it all into memory?

Comment: Yes, that's the challenge -- memory issues with very large datasets (RAM and dataset size dependent). You are caught in the horns of a dilemma: To reduced your memory footprint you need to read slices directly from the H5 dataset with **ascending indices**. To use **random indices**, you need enough memory to store in the equivalent numpy array in RAM. To get random slices from H5 datasets, I suspect you will need a mapping array. Start with random indices, create a second sorted array, plus a mapping array to go from sorted to random.

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution is to pre-sort the desired indices as follow:

```py
idx = np.sort([3,1])
random_subset = h5py.File('example1.h5', 'r')['data'][idx]
```